# How to handle Java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, serialization

I have created a java program which works with java I/O. I have implemented Serializable interface, but it still cause java.io.NotSerializableException on the following part of my code while I am trying to write objects into a file:

```
         oos.writeObject(ep);
```

How it is possible while I am implementing serializable? should I do another works besides implementing this interface?

Comment: Well, *something* must not be serializable. Shall we play 20 questions?

Answer (score 6):

Usually that means, that another object that your object you are trying to serialize holds a reference to is not serializable. If you post your code and the exceptions stacktrace it would be a lot easier to tell.